# What does the term “mohel” mean in Hilchot Melicha (salting)?

Tags: words, kashering-kosherization

In Siman 69:20, there’s reference to a “ma’aseh Rashi”, in which Rashi rules that what comes out after shiur melicha is “mohel” and not “dam”. What does “mohel” mean here?

Comment: Where is this Siman 69:20 you cite, so that others can see it inside? Is that Tur? Shulchan Aruch? Beis Yosef? Aruch HaShulchan?

Comment: @DonielF can't be Tur. It doesn't have subsections.

Comment: I remember when I learnt melicha we translated mahul as water based juice,that it isn't dam,but rather like water.

Comment: I think the loshon is ma li mayim,ma li mahul.

Comment: AFAICT, this term does not appear in Shulchan Aruch or Tur on the topic, but it does appear in Beis Yosef YD 67:10 and 69:15,49,51, as well as Aruch HaShulchan several times throughout the lengthy YD 69 (but not in §20). Rashi is only cited in the first of those, but not as saying anything remotely similar as what’s written here. Did you misquote and misremember the details of what he said? Can you provide *anything* to help us find the original quote, to confirm if the current answers actually make sense in context?

Comment: @msh210 Some of the newer editions insert subsections on halachos corresponding to the subsections in Shulchan Aruch. I thought maybe he got confused and thought they were originally in the Tur as well.

Comment: Related to Shulchan Aruch 69:20. See Chullin 112b, second Tosafot, 8th line from the end.

Answer (score 5):

The Sefer Yoreh Binah (Practical guide to the terminology of Yoreh Deah- Rabbi Daniel Yaakov Travis):

> **מוהל**
>
> **Definition:** Liquid of [*heter*](//judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/585) that is discharged from meat after the *shiur melicha* [=amount of time necessary for salting].

Comment: So you're saying that Rashi (cited in the question) is giving a definition of _mohel_ rather than an example of it?

Answer (score 4):

Jastrow translates it as secretion: https://www.sefaria.org/Jastrow%2C_%D7%9E%D7%95%D6%B9%D7%94%D6%B7%D7%9C.1?lang=bi&with=Jastrow&lang2=en

Answer (score 3):

In modern Hebrew, Mohel means dilution (למהול = to dilute). I think that it means something like that here, too.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Simcha Daniel and thanks for this first answer. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!